# What's the difference between CSS UI framework and jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, css

I noticed that CSS Framework such as `bootstrap` and `w3.css` can create webpage ui widgets such as `button`. 
But Javascript library `jQuery-ui` can also create `button`

What's the difference between these two approaches?

Comment: The major difference appears to be that one is a CSS and the other a JavaScript library?

Comment: isn't this question about differences between a "pure" CSS Framework and a CSS/JavaScript Framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Bootstrap (assuming v3):**

Quoting directly from [bootstrap's](http://getbootstrap.com/) website:

> Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JS framework for
>   developing responsive, mobile first projects on the web.

Which means that it provides the following features:

1. Is a **framework** which allows you to create responsive web application which work across multiple devices like PC, Tablets and Mobile.
2. It provides a 12 column responsive grid system which works across devices.
3. Supports [SASS Preprocessor](http://sass-lang.com/guide), which make writing CSS much more efficient with concepts like variables, mixins, inheritance etc.
4. Also provides a wide variety of [components](http://getbootstrap.com/components/) which makes web development a breeze. These components are built using javascript and jQuery.
5. A lot of [themes](https://themes.getbootstrap.com/) which you can use for your web app.

**jQueryUI**

Quoting directly from [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/):

> jQuery UI is a curated set of user interface interactions, effects,
>   widgets, and themes built on top of the jQuery JavaScript Library.
>   Whether you're building highly interactive web applications or you
>   just need to add a date picker to a form control, jQuery UI is the
>   perfect choice.

Which basically means that it provides:

1. A set of widgets/components like calendar, dropdowns etc which you can use with your web application.
2. Interactions like drag and drop.
3. Themes for creating custom look and feel for your components.

To sum it up, Bootstrap is a framework for building responsive web applications whereas jQueryUI is essentially a widget/interaction library. Note that you can use jQueryUI widgets inside your Bootstrap based application.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is the author. Another difference might be what components they provide.

They're doing the same thing but just have different authors. Even though Bootstrap is a CSS framework, it's still using JavaScript for some of the interactive elements like "collapse" (which jQuery UI calls "accordion"). Bootstrap wrote their JavaScript to be compatible with jQuery.